# Running two instances of Fuse each under a different JVM version

Tags: java, jvm, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I would like to (temporarily) run on the same server an instance of JBOSS Fuse 6.0 using JVM 1.7 and an  instance of FuseSource Fuse 7.0 using JVM 1.6.  Is this possible?  I cannot find anywhere in the documentation where I can specify what JVM for each to use at startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bin/fuse` or `bin/fuseesb` scripts look at the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to figure out which JVM installation to use.

You should be able to set that variable before starting the container to ensure it's running with the correct JVM installation.